# How to display all the users created by a particular user in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

For example: if a user creates n number of users . I want to display the n number of users created by that particular user alone in django .

I can't come up with a solution.

Do i have to create a model like profile with OnetoOnemodel of user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fair question, but no, you can't guarantee knowledge of who created the user. Users just exist in a database and thus can be created completed outside of Django. What you could do is create a `UserAdmin` and overwrite `save_model` to set some field, i.e, `creator`, as the current user:

```
# set creator as logged-in user
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.creator = request.user
    super(MyUserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

But this still does not guarantee an audit of any user; only those created through the admin. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/) for more on admin methods.